# can I send a list of objects including images using FormData object from view to the controller by ajax call?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a list of forms including image files and collect them using jquery and try to send them to the controller, I tried to send one form that included an image, and working fine, but when I send the list, not work

Comment: You need to be more specific. Show at least the code gathering the form data and sending it. If possible in a reproducible example or at least in a shortened version, so we do not have to dig through unnessecary code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can send a list of objects including images using the `FormData` object from view to the `controller` by an `AJAX` call.

To do this, you can create a new instance of the `FormData` object, append each form in the list to the `FormData` object, and then send the `FormData` object through an `AJAX` call to the `controller`.

Here is an example that demonstrates how to do it:

```
// Create a new instance of the FormData object
var formData = new FormData();

// Iterate over each form in the list
$('form').each(function() {

  // Append the form data to the FormData object
  var form = $(this)[0];
  var formdata = new FormData(form);
  
  formData.append('forms[]', formdata);
});

// Send the FormData object through an AJAX call to the controller
$.ajax({
  url: 'your_controller_url',
  type: 'POST',
  data: formData,
  contentType: false,
  processData: false,
  success: function(response) {
    // Handle the response from the controller
  },
  error: function(error) {
    // Handle any errors that occur during the AJAX call
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make it as the following example:

```
const formData = new FormData();

formData.append('email',this.formObj.email);

    for (let i = 0; i < this.formObj.Attachments.length; i++) {

    formData.append(`files[${i}].property1`, 
        this.formObj.Attachments[i].property1);

    formData.append(`files[${i}].property2`, 
        this.formObj.Attachments[i].property2);

    formData.append(`files[${i}].file`, 
        this.formObj.Attachments[i].file, 
        this.formObj.Attachments[i].file.name);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**